# Abstract class, use type of inheritor in generic method

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, unity-game-engine

I have an abstract class that is supposed to be inherited by various other classes and be attached to a `GameObject`  using the `Attach` method, as it does some initialization work *(removed in example for simplicity)*.

```
public abstract class GameBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool initialized = false;

    public void Initialize(GameState gameState)
    {
        initialized = true;
    }

    public static T Attach<T>(GameObject parent, GameState gameState) where T : GameBehaviour
    {
        T behaviour = parent.AddComponent<T>();
        behaviour.Initialize(gameState);
        return behaviour;
    }
}
```

I then have another class called `WorldManager` and `WorldRenderer` that both inherit the abstract `GameBehaviour` class.

To "initialize" objects of these classes I use the following code:

```
WorldManager manager = WorldManager.Attach<WorldManager>(gameObject, this);
WorldRenderer renderer = WorldRenderer.Attach<WorldRenderer>(gameObject, this);
```

Now, obviously, the `<WorldManager>` and `<WorldRenderer>` feels redundant. My question is whether it's possible to change the `Attach` method as to not need the generic type but instead use the type of it's inheritor, if that makes sense. There's probably some C# concept I am forgetting about or is not aware about.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can make the `GameBehaviour` class generic instead of the method. Obviously the consequence is that you cannot use the `Attach` method to attach other types.

The generic constraint makes it look like you are going in circles, but the C# typing system allows this just fine.

```
public abstract class GameBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {
    private bool initialized = false;

    public void Initialize(GameState gameState)
    {
        initialized = true;
    }
}
public abstract class GameBehaviour<T> : GameBehaviour where T: GameBehaviour<T>
{
    public static T Attach(GameObject parent, GameState gameState)
    {
        T behaviour = parent.AddComponent<T>();
        behaviour.Initialize(gameState);
        return behaviour;
    }
}

public class WorldManager: GameBehaviour<WorldManager> { ... }
public class WorldRenderer: GameBehaviour<WorldRenderer> { ... }
```

Usage:

```
WorldManager manager = WorldManager.Attach(gameObject, this);
WorldRenderer renderer = WorldRenderer.Attach(gameObject, this);
```

Comment: Ah, I see! That moves the seemingly redundant `<WorldManager>` to the class declaration instead, but I prefer that over the other way.

Will use this solution unless something else comes up. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you leave the generic parameter at the method level, then the compiler has nothing in infer the type from, since the T is not used in any parameters.

Comment: I would suggest to replace the where T: GameBehaviour<T> by something like where T: IGameBehaviour if that is possible. This way you would decouple it a bit.

Comment: @Andre What would that achieve? The purpose is to do `public class SomeClass: GameBehaviour<SomeClass>` where the `T` is the class you are defining. Nothing is gained by replacing `where T: GameBehaviour<T>` with `T: IGameBehaviour`.

Comment: @Maarten that could be a first step to use composition instead of inheritance (in case you don't have a really good argument for using inheritance) and make testing easier.

Comment: @Andre The generic's purpose is used solely to specify the return type for the `Attach` method. Therefore the actively specified T is the same type as the class that you are defining. Therefore, IMHO, it doesn't matter how the  generic constraint is specified, since it doesn't have to be able to take something like `public class SomeClass : GameBehaviour<SomeOtherClass> { }`.

Comment: @Andre It only has to be able to take `public class SomeClass: GameBehaviour<SomeClass> { } `. Of course, this only applied if the `Attach` method in `WorldManager` can/should only return an instance of type `WorldManager`, and nothing else.